# The product of a function that vanishes at infinity and a continuous bounded one

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff completely regular space. Let $B(X)$ denote the algebra of real bounded functions, and let

$$B_\infty (X) = \{ f \in B (X) \mid f^{-1} ([r , \infty)) \text{ is compact} \ \forall r>0 \}$$

be (by definition) the subalgebra of the functions that vanish at infinity.

I don't think that $B_\infty (X)$ is an ideal,

> but if $f \in B_\infty (X)$ and $g$ is *continuous* and bounded, does $fg$ vanish at infinity? (Take them positive, for simplicity.)

Empirical evidence suggests so (for instance, try $f$ the characteristic function of some compact subset), but I am looking for a proof.

Notice that if $r>0$ is fixed and $K_r = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) g(x) \ge r \}$, then $x \in K_r$ implies $g(x) \ne 0$, therefore

$$K_r = \bigcup _{t>0} \left\{x \in X \mid g(x) = t \text{ and } f(x) \ge \frac r t \right\} = \bigcup _{t > 0} g^{-1} (\{t\}) \cap f^{-1} \left( \left[ \frac r t, \infty \right) \right)$$

and this leads nowhere, since an arbitrary union of compact subsets is not necessarily compact, not even closed.

Comment: I have not read it carefully, but isn't it trivial that the product of a function that vanishes at infinity with a bounded function must vanish at infinity?

Comment: Well, prove it and I shall immediately accept your answer! It is trivial when $f$ is continuous, which is not the case here. I do not even know whether what I am asking about is true or not, a counterexample would also qualify as an answer.

Comment: I assume the catch is in the definition, where you require that $f^{-1} ([r , \infty))$ is compact, not just bounded.

Comment: What does “bounded” mean in an arbitrary Hausdorff space?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos These are complex functions, so I assume that $f(X)$ is bounded in the complex plane

Comment: The set $f^{-1}\bigl([r,\infty)\bigr)$ is a subset of $X$, not of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see your point, the OP did not refer to $f^{-1}\bigl([r,\infty)\bigr)$ as "bounded", but it was me, who did it in a comment. I don't know what "bounded" means in an arbitrary Hausdorff space (one could possibly come up with a suitable definition, along pseudocompact), I didn't think when I posted that comment, or rather I was thinking of the metric case.

Comment: Do you mean $|f|^{-1}([r, \infty))$? Otherwise you are only discussing a small subset of the codomain of $f$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Thank you, I have changed "complex" to "real", in order to stick to a body of texts that I am reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be trivial, but not in an obvious way. Since $f$ is positive and vanishes at infinity, it is [upper-semicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuous_function). Since $g$ is continuous, it too is upper-semicontinuous. Since both are assumed positive (an essential hypothesis), it follows that $fg$ is upper-semicontinuous (see Proposition 2 on page 362 of Bourbaki's ["General Topology: Chapters 1–4"](https://books.google.com/books?id=SBdtCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA362)), therefore $(fg)^{-1} ([r, \infty))$ is closed for all $r>0$.

Next, since $g$ is bounded, for every $r>0$ we have $(fg)^{-1} ([r, \infty)) \subseteq f^{-1} \left( \left[ \frac r {\sup g}, \infty \right) \right)$ which is compact by assumption. Since $(fg)^{-1} ([r, \infty))$ is [a closed subset of a compact one](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Subspace_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact), it itself is compact, hence $fg$ vanishes at infinity.

It seems that the topological hypotheses on $X$ (being Hausdorff and completely regular) may be dropped, since they don't appear to be used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a shot at this.  This proof seems too simple.

I am going to assume you really meant to define $B_\infty$ by (see Paul's comment) 
$$
B_\infty(X)=\{f\in B(X)\, |\ |f|^{-1}([r, \infty)) \mathrm{\ is\ compact\  }\forall r>0\}
$$
where $|f|^{-1}([r, \infty)) := \{x\in X |\  \mathrm{abs}(f(x))\geq r\}$.

Let $h(x):=f(x)g(x)$ where $f(x)\in B_\infty(X)$, $g(x)\in B(X)$, $g$ is continuous, and $m=\sup_x |g(x)|$. Then for any $r>0$,
$$
|h|^{-1}([r, \infty))\subset |f|^{-1}([r/m, \infty))
$$
which is compact and $|h|^{-1}([r, \infty))$ is closed, so $|h|^{-1}([r, \infty))$ is compact.  This proves that $h\in B_\infty(X)$.

Why is $|h|^{-1}([r, \infty))$ closed?

Assume $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $\{x_n\}\subset |h|^{-1}([r, \infty)).$  We will prove that $x\in |h|^{-1}([r, \infty)).$  Let $z=|g(x)|$. Then
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}|h(x_n)|\geq r,$$
$$\liminf|f(x_n)||g(x_n)|\geq r,$$
$$\liminf|f(x_n)|z\geq r, \quad \mathrm{and}$$
$$\liminf|f(x_n)|\geq r/z.$$

So for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists and $N_\epsilon\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $|f(x_n)|>r/z-\epsilon$ when $n>N_\epsilon$.

Thus, for all $\epsilon>0$, $x_n\in |f|^{-1}([r/z-\epsilon, \infty))$ when $n>N_\epsilon$ and consequently $x\in |f|^{-1}([r/z-\epsilon, \infty)).$
We can conclude that $|f(x)|\geq r/z$ and hence
$$|h(x)| =|f(x)g(x)|= |f(x)|z\geq r$$
proving that $x\in |h(x)|^{-1}([r, \infty))$ and proving that $|h(x)|^{-1}([r, \infty))$ is closed.

Comment: Why is $|h|^{-1} ([r, \infty))$ closed? You are making the same mistake that has been made in another answer posted here, currently deleted by its author (so you cannot see it). If $f$ were continuous, you would be right - but it is not!

Comment: @Alex LOL, maybe we should not delete our erroneous answers.  I don't see any reason why $|h|^{-1}([r,\infty))$ is closed !

Comment: @Alex.  I wrote out the sketch of a proof that  $|h|^{-1}([r, \infty))$ is closed, but I am not very confident about it because I am rather sleepy.  I will get some sleep and look at it tomorrow.  Sorry!

Comment: I haven't read all of your new argument, but there are at least two mistakes in it: the first is that you work with sequences, even though $X$ need not be first countable (you should use nets); the second, much more serious, is that you silently use that $\lim h(x_n) = \lim f(x_n) \lim g(x_n)$ which is not necessarily true, because it is not clear that $\lim f(x_n)$ exists (remember that $f$ is not necessarily continuous). In fact, you make this same error again when you write the expression $\lim h(x_n)$ - why would this limit exist, given that $h$ is not known a priori to be continuous?

Comment: I will take a look at it later when I have some time.

Comment: @Alex  The problem with the limit is fixed with liminf.     I'm not sure that I can fix the remainder of the proof by switching to nets.    So, at this point, I think the argument only works in nicer spaces.

Comment: Changing from $\lim$ to $\liminf$ changes much more: if $(s_n)$ is a sequence of positive numbers, saying that $\liminf s_n \ge s$ does NOT mean that for every $\epsilon$ there exists an $N_\epsilon$ such that $s_n \ge s - \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N_\epsilon$. Rather, it means that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N_\epsilon$ such that for infinitely many (but not necessarily all!) $n \ge N_\epsilon$ it is true that $s_n \ge s - \epsilon$. Remember that $\liminf$ is the smallest of the limit points of $(s_n)$, i.e. there exists a *subsequence* of $(s_n)$ tending to it.

Comment: @Alex.   Hmm.  Maybe I am misunderstanding something. (It would not be the first time!)  Here is a quote from the Wikipedia "The limit inferior of $x_n$ is the largest real number $b$ such that, for any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $x_n>b−\epsilon$  for all $n>N$."  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Interpretation) As far as I can tell, I used "$\liminf$" correctly.  So I guess I disagree with the first two sentences of your comment, but I do agree with your last sentence.  What do you think?

Comment: Oh yes, obviously. While typing the above comment I kept having in mind $|s_n - s| < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$, as for limits.